# How can I modify this function to take into account "months" and "years"?

Tags: javascript, math, datetime, date, time

```
function prettyDate(time){
    var date = time,
        diff = (((new Date()).getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000),
        day_diff = Math.floor(diff / 86400);
    if ( isNaN(day_diff) || day_diff < 0 || day_diff >= 31 ){
        return;
    }
    return day_diff == 0 && (
            diff < 60 && Math.floor(diff) + " seconds" ||
            diff < 120 && "1 minute" ||
            diff < 3600 && Math.floor( diff / 60 ) + " min" ||
            diff < 7200 && "1 hour" ||
            diff < 86400 && Math.floor( diff / 3600 ) + " hours") ||
        day_diff == 1 && "1 day" ||
        day_diff < 7 && day_diff + " days" ||
        day_diff < 31 && Math.ceil( day_diff / 7 ) + " weeks";
}
```

My friend helped me write this function to turn dates into "pretty dates".  The problem is, right now it doesn't handle months.  If you look at the code, it returns nothing when the difference of days is more than 31 days.

What can I do to make this work with months and years?

Would this take care of it, added to the last line?

```
Math.ceil( day_diff / 31 ) + " months";
```

Comment: What exactly is a "month" and a "year"?

Comment: Of course 1 month = 31 days and 1 year = 365.  Everyone knows that.  Also 1 year = 11.77419 months, of course apart from leap years when 1 year = 11.80645 months.  (Obviously I have excluded leap seconds from this analysis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a few clauses to the end of the `return` expression and also remove the `day_diff >= 31` guard:

```
function prettyDate(time){
    var date = time,
        diff = (((new Date()).getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000),
        day_diff = Math.floor(diff / 86400);
    if ( isNaN(day_diff) || day_diff < 0){
        return;
    }
    return day_diff == 0 && (
            diff < 60 && Math.floor(diff) + " seconds" ||
            diff < 120 && "1 minute" ||
            diff < 3600 && Math.floor( diff / 60 ) + " min" ||
            diff < 7200 && "1 hour" ||
            diff < 86400 && Math.floor( diff / 3600 ) + " hours") ||
        day_diff == 1 && "1 day" ||
        day_diff < 7 && day_diff + " days" ||
        day_diff < 31 && Math.ceil( day_diff / 7 ) + " weeks" ||
        day_diff < 365 && Math.ceil( day_diff / 31 ) + " months" ||
        Math.ceil( day_diff / 365 ) + " years";
}
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/4MqjY/)**.

Comment: Will display 12 months if 341 < day_diff < 365

Comment: @meze: Will also display "4 weeks" if 27 < day_diff < 31. I don't think it's so clear-cut what exactly should happen in those cases, so I left it as is.

Comment: You would have to do some more coding as not every month has 31 days.

Comment: @Sirko: The very first thing I did here was ask the OP what a "month" is. Please read the comments on the question itself.

Comment: @Jon if he defined a month is 31 days, then 4 weeks != a month

Comment: @meze: ...and if he defined a year as 365 days, then 12 months is not a year. The whole issue is confusing, which is why the function was not designed to go above weeks in the first place.

Comment: @Jon I don't find it confusing.. 12 months is always a year. What is really confusing about the original function is that if day_diff == 30, it'll display '5 weeks' which is 35 days instead of 1 month.